# how to find all the child nodes inside the matched elements (including text nodes)?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

in jquery its quite simple

for instance

```
$("br").parent().contents().each(function() {
```

but for nokogiri, xpath,

its not working out quite well

```
var = doc.xpath('//br/following-sibling::text()|//br/preceding-sibling::text()').map do |fruit| fruit.to_s.strip end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA.read)
fruits = doc.xpath('//br/../text()').map { |text| text.content.strip }
p fruits


__END__
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    apple<br>
    banana<br>
    cherry<br>
    orange<br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with nokogiri, but are you trying to find all the children of any element that contains a `<br/>`?  If so, then try:

```
//*[br]/node()
```

In any case, using text() will only match text nodes, and not any sibling elements, which may or may not be what you want.  If you actually only want text nodes, then

```
//*[br]/text()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: He is looking for `//br/../text()` which matches all text nodes at the   same level as the break.